# Stop data being read as factors by default with read.zoo

Tags: r, csv, time-series, zoo

I am using the `zoo` package in R to analyse time series of data. I have the following data file:

```
Date(dd-mm-yy),Time(hh:mm:ss),Julian_Day,AOT_1640,AOT_1020,AOT_870,AOT_675,AOT_667,AOT_555,AOT_551,AOT_532,AOT_531,AOT_500,AOT_490,AOT_443,AOT_440,AOT_412,AOT_380,AOT_340,Water(cm),%TripletVar_1640,%TripletVar_1020,%TripletVar_870,%TripletVar_675,%TripletVar_667,%TripletVar_555,%TripletVar_551,%TripletVar_532,%TripletVar_531,%TripletVar_500,%TripletVar_490,%TripletVar_443,%TripletVar_440,%TripletVar_412,%TripletVar_380,%TripletVar_340,%WaterError,440-870Angstrom,380-500Angstrom,440-675Angstrom,500-870Angstrom,340-440Angstrom,440-675Angstrom(Polar),Last_Processing_Date(dd/mm/yyyy),Solar_Zenith_Angle
29:03:2011,09:26:28,88.393380,N/A,0.490230,0.553836,0.707512,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0.911939,N/A,N/A,0.984430,N/A,1.046517,1.081283,1.632430,N/A,4.597345,4.551429,3.216097,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,2.587552,N/A,N/A,2.694179,N/A,2.085042,2.522511,2.309844,0.851964,0.497006,0.789257,0.898093,0.362423,N/A,13/04/2011,58.822462
29:03:2011,09:41:28,88.403796,N/A,0.440362,0.513093,0.676703,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0.893867,N/A,N/A,0.965588,N/A,1.034943,1.079975,1.654521,N/A,12.867837,12.687550,11.037238,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,9.345739,N/A,N/A,8.423888,N/A,8.421787,9.334135,1.622026,0.937815,0.529939,0.852553,0.999260,0.431102,N/A,13/04/2011,57.070624
29:03:2011,10:11:29,88.424641,N/A,0.565148,0.654724,0.842142,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,1.070556,N/A,N/A,1.144966,N/A,1.208759,1.242663,1.666760,N/A,9.933505,9.499251,8.327355,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,6.781617,N/A,N/A,6.612952,N/A,5.600500,5.630695,1.302058,0.826713,0.438445,0.736362,0.884554,0.316539,N/A,13/04/2011,53.916620
29:03:2011,10:17:46,88.429005,N/A,0.593881,0.681572,0.866620,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,1.095508,N/A,N/A,1.168008,N/A,1.233022,1.268572,1.704882,N/A,4.072782,3.752197,3.210935,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,2.389567,N/A,N/A,2.385582,N/A,1.653326,1.015620,0.728711,0.798185,0.427272,0.716165,0.853963,0.319100,N/A,13/04/2011,53.323057
29:03:2011,10:26:27,88.435035,N/A,0.636627,0.714175,0.884887,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,1.092220,N/A,N/A,1.167024,N/A,1.224264,1.271774,1.626393,N/A,16.400200,10.585139,6.513873,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,3.169704,N/A,N/A,4.085949,N/A,3.963741,8.663229,10.035231,0.724581,0.411533,0.659996,0.764539,0.329073,N/A,13/04/2011,52.544475
```

I am trying to read it using the following code:

```
f <- function(d, t) as.chron(paste(as.Date(chron(d, format='d:m:y')), t))

z = read.zoo("110329_110329_Chilbolton.lev10", sep=',', header=T, index = 1:2, FUN=f, as.is=F, dec=".")
```

But all of the columns of the dataset are being read as factors - so, when I do `summary(z)` I get output like:

```
X.TripletVar_340    X.WaterError X440.870Angstrom X380.500Angstrom X440.675Angstrom X500.870Angstrom
 1.015620:1        0.728711:1     0.724581:1       0.411533:1       0.659996:1       0.764539:1      
 2.522511:1        1.302058:1     0.798185:1       0.427272:1       0.716165:1       0.853963:1      
 5.630695:1        1.622026:1     0.826713:1       0.438445:1       0.736362:1       0.884554:1      
 8.663229:1        2.309844:1     0.851964:1       0.497006:1       0.789257:1       0.898093:1      
 9.334135:1       10.035231:1     0.937815:1       0.529939:1       0.852553:1       0.999260:1
```

How can I stop it reading the data as factors by default? The data is read fine by `read.table` without any extra parameters to tell it to make sure everything stays as numbers not factors - so why is `read.zoo` behaving differently?

I suppose I could use colClasses to specify the type of each column, but I'd rather not do this in case the order of the columns in the dataset is changed - getting it to convert to numbers by default, and then try factors if that doesn't work would be far better.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been diagnosed already but let us add this so that we have an example of a `read.zoo` statement that could be used here.

There are two problems: (1) the NAs are represented as N/A rather than NA so we must tell it that.  (2) the second last column is not numeric. zoo represents the data as a matrix so it must all be numeric (factor zoo objects are supported too but they can't be mixed).

Try this (where we have added a second data line to the example for good measure).  Be sure to use the most recent version of zoo to run the example data since the `text=` argument (which specifies the text of the data itself rather than the filename) was only added recently.  Also note that from within R `?read.zoo` gives help and `vignette("zoo-read")` gives a document entirely devoted to `read.zoo` examples.

```
Lines <- "Date(dd-mm-yy),Time(hh:mm:ss),Julian_Day,AOT_1640,AOT_1020,AOT_870,AOT_675,AOT_667,AOT_555,AOT_551,AOT_532,AOT_531,AOT_500,AOT_490,AOT_443,AOT_440,AOT_412,AOT_380,AOT_340,Water(cm),%TripletVar_1640,%TripletVar_1020,%TripletVar_870,%TripletVar_675,%TripletVar_667,%TripletVar_555,%TripletVar_551,%TripletVar_532,%TripletVar_531,%TripletVar_500,%TripletVar_490,%TripletVar_443,%TripletVar_440,%TripletVar_412,%TripletVar_380,%TripletVar_340,%WaterError,440-870Angstrom,380-500Angstrom,440-675Angstrom,500-870Angstrom,340-440Angstrom,440-675Angstrom(Polar),Last_Processing_Date(dd/mm/yyyy),Solar_Zenith_Angle
29:03:2011,09:26:28,88.393380,N/A,0.490230,0.553836,0.707512,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0.911939,N/A,N/A,0.984430,N/A,1.046517,1.081283,1.632430,N/A,4.597345,4.551429,3.216097,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,2.587552,N/A,N/A,2.694179,N/A,2.085042,2.522511,2.309844,0.851964,0.497006,0.789257,0.898093,0.362423,N/A,13/04/2011,58.822462
29:03:2012,09:26:28,88.393380,N/A,0.490230,0.553836,0.707512,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,0.911939,N/A,N/A,0.984430,N/A,1.046517,1.081283,1.632430,N/A,4.597345,4.551429,3.216097,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,2.587552,N/A,N/A,2.694179,N/A,2.085042,2.522511,2.309844,0.851964,0.497006,0.789257,0.898093,0.362423,N/A,13/04/2011,58.822462"

library(chron)
library(zoo)
colClasses <- c("character", "character", rep("numeric", 43))
colClasses[44] <- "NULL" # zap the non-numeric column
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = "N/A",
    index = 1:2, colClasses = colClasses, FUN = function(d, t)
        as.chron(paste(d, t), "%d:%m:%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data file poses two problems for `read.zoo`.

First, it uses `N/A` to denote missing values, rather than the string `NA`, which `read.table()` expects by default.  This can be fixed by setting `na.strings="N/A"`.

The second problem is that the data file's next-to-last column, `Last_Processing_Date.dd.mm.yyyy`, contains character strings.

But, according to the zoo FAQ document [(warning, PDF)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-faq.pdf):

> A "zoo" object may be (1) a numeric vector, (2) a numeric matrix or (3) a factor but may
>   not contain both a numeric vector and factor.

When 'asked' to read in a bunch of columns that contain both numeric character values, converting everything to factors is the only way that `read.zoo()` can produce an object fitting one of those three criteria.

If you remove the offending column, and specify your missing value string, everything works without a hitch. If you do need both numeric and factor columns, the FAQ linked above suggests several possible approaches.

```
z <- read.table("110329_110329_Chilbolton.lev10", sep=",", header=T,
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="N/A")
z$Last_Processing_Date.dd.mm.yyyy. <- NULL
z <- zoo(x=z[,-1:-2], order.by=f(z[[1]], z[[2]]))
summary(z)

     Index                       Julian_Day       AOT_1640      AOT_1020     
 Min.   :(03/29/11 09:26:28)   Min.   :88.39   Min.   : NA   Min.   :0.4404  
 1st Qu.:(03/29/11 09:41:28)   1st Qu.:88.40   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:0.4902  
 Median :(03/29/11 10:11:29)   Median :88.42   Median : NA   Median :0.5651  
 Mean   :(03/29/11 10:00:44)   Mean   :88.42   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :0.5452  
 3rd Qu.:(03/29/11 10:17:46)   3rd Qu.:88.43   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.:0.5939  
 Max.   :(03/29/11 10:26:27)   Max.   :88.44   Max.   : NA   Max.   :0.6366
```

Comment: Correct...if you look in `read.zoo()`, you'll see that the data get coerced by `as.matrix()`, which "will return a character matrix if there is any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column".

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that you are importing from an Excel file and not taking the time to make the "N/A" values into proper NA values.  That results in the columns being considered non-numeric. The zoo package need the coredata to be a matrix and that severely constrains the option available for processing. Everything needs to be numeric. Even if you put in stringsAsFactors = FALSE you would still get character columns where you expected numeric.

If you read in with read.table and set `as.is=TRUE,` you can overcome the factor problem. You then need to coerce the columns that you want to be numeric and drop the trailing date columns that will come in with a name of "Last_Processing_Date.dd.mm.yyyy."

I would do this first:

```
z = read.table(file.choose(), sep=',', header=T,  as.is=TRUE, dec=".")
```

And then choose the columns to coerce to numeric:

```
z[ , 3:43] <- sapply(z[ , 3:43], as.numeric)
```

Keeping that date column intact in the 44th column. Then decide which columns should go into the zoo object.

Edit: I see Gabor Grothendieck has addressed these problems as well which is as it should be since he is one of the authors of the package.

Answer (score 1):

The `...` in `read.zoo()` will let you pass a `stringsAsFactors = F` on to `read.table()`. That should do the trick.

Comment: +1 Note that I strongly believe that `TRUE` / `FALSE` should always be written in long form.  It's too easy to declare a variable called F which may then cause all kinds of unexpected things where you wrote `F` for `FALSE`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however that doesn't seem to work I still get all of the numerical output as factors (no difference to the output above). Any other ideas?

Comment: Arg...sorry robin. I couldn't test for sure since your code didn't work for me. I think I'm missing that `as.chron` function. Let me track it down and see...

Comment: `as.chron` is in the chron package if that helps...`library(chron)` should load it.

Comment: @Andrie: my personal favorite is: `F <- TRUE; T <- FALSE`. ;-)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich LOL...disaster!